# I am having difficulties during manipulating log file with awk and shellscript

Tags: awk, associative-array

I have a difficulty with awk.
I want to concatenate columns if first fields and 3field matches from 2 different files with awk.
Probably, It'd better to use array function, I am very confused with it.

Input Example

```
file1
0x11110293030,2019-10-13T12:13:39,8.8.8.8,KeitheNoop,workgroupa
0x22222211111,2019-10-12T12:17:23,8.8.8.8,KattheNoop,workgroups
0x21034922113,2019-10-14T15:12:63,8.8.8.8,KoitheNoop,workgroupz

file2
0x11110293030,2019-10-13T12:22:44,8.8.8.8,KeiLeftAll,workgroupk
0x22222211111,2019-10-14T12:19:23,8.8.8.8,KattheNoop,workgroups
0x21034922113,2019-10-14T15:34:63,8.8.8.8,KoitheNoop,workgroupz
```

Expected output

```
0x11110293030,8.8.8.8,KeitheNoop,workgroupa,2019-10-13T12:13:39 ~ 2019-10-13T12:22:44,8.8.8.8,KeiLeftAll,workgroupk
0x22222211111,8.8.8.8,KattheNoop,workgroups,2019-10-12T12:17:23 ~ 2019-10-14T12:19:23,8.8.8.8,KattheNoop,workgroups
0x21034922113,8.8.8.8,KoitheNoop,workgroupz,2019-10-14T15:12:63 ~ 2019-10-14T15:34:63,8.8.8.8,KoitheNoop,workgroupz
```

if you can please also briefly explain about the codes why it works.
Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Comment: Which code are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F',' '{
  if (FNR==NR){
    a[$1"@"$3]=$4","$5","$2
  }
  else if ($1"@"$3 in a){
    print $1","$3","a[$1"@"$3]" ~ "$2","$3","$4","$5
  }
}' file1 file2
```

When the first file is processed (`FNR==NR` means the input record number of the current file equals the total record number, i.e. the first file is being processed), save the string containing fourth, fifth and second field in array `a` with the first and third field combined with `@` as index.

When the second file is processed (`else if`) and the combined key of first and third field of your current line exists in the array, print first and third field, the saved array value, tilde and fields 2 - 5 of the current line.

Your question looks like "homework" and I strongly suggest you try it yourself if you want to understand how `awk` arrays work.

Comment: Thanks a lot you made me get it. Actually that file already parsed from my pc and I manipulated it with gensub function and then I tried 3-4 hours already that's why I asked. Unfortunately its not my homework, I wish it was though.